# How to test charge.refund.updated(status=failed) with stripe trigger in CLI?

Tags: stripe-payments

I tried

```
stripe trigger charge.refund.updated \
  --skip charge \
  --remove refund:charge \
  --add refund:payment_intent=pi_xxx \
  --override refund:status='failed'
```

but it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe CLI has a [feature](https://stripe.com/docs/cli/fixtures) where you could write your own fixtures and run them.
What I did in this instance is copying the fixture of `charge.refund` from [github](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/blob/master/pkg/fixtures/triggers/charge.refunded.json) and modified it so it uses the card that [@orakaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3631795/orakaro) mentioned in his answer.

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "template_version": 0
  },
  "fixtures": [
    {
      "name": "charge",
      "path": "/v1/charges",
      "method": "post",
      "params": {
        "source": "tok_refundFail",
        "amount": 100,
        "currency": "usd",
        "description": "(created by Stripe CLI)"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "refund",
      "path": "/v1/refunds",
      "method": "post",
      "params": {
        "charge": "${charge:id}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would save that json locally and using stripe-cli would call `stripe fixtures <path-to-your-json-file>` which will trigger the `charge.refund.updated` event with a status failed.

Comment: In which part of this json file I should mention the refund state?

Comment: Basically the `"source": "tok_refundFail",` is the magic token used to tell Stripe to fail the refund. You can read more about this testing card [here](https://stripe.com/docs/testing?numbers-or-method-or-token=tokens#refunds).

Answer (score 2):

Your command will call /v1/refunds under the hood, and [the API's parameters](https://stripe.com/docs/api/refunds/create) doesn't allow to specify status.

There is no easy way to successfully send a Create Refund API and immediately get a Refund with status = failed. But instead, you can create a PaymentIntent from a Card that [guaranteed result in a failed refund](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#refunds).

> The charge succeeds. If you initiate a refund, its status begins as
> succeeded. Some time later, its status transitions to failed and sends
> a charge.refund.updated webhook event.

Comment: This is a good answer.  It means can test it without special interactions with the CLI